# Optimization problem with reciprocal of posynomial

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, geometric-programming

Let $S_1,S_2\subseteq [N]$.

I am dealing with an optimization problem that is compliant with the GP formulation except for a set of inequalities constraints of the type:

$$
\left(\prod_{i \in S_1} x_i \left(\sum_{j\in S_1^c} y_j\right)\right)^{-1} + \left(\prod_{k\in S_2} x_k \left(\sum_{l \in S_2^c} y_l\right)\right)^{-1} \le 1,
$$
where the summations and products are taken over different sets, and the objective
$$
\min_{x,y} a_{i,j}\left(\prod_{i\in S_1} x_i \left(\sum_{j\in S_1^c} y_j\right)\right) + a_{k,l}\left(\prod_{k\in S_2} x_k \left(\sum_{l\in S_2^c} y_l\right)\right),
$$
where $a\succeq 0$.
Obviously, the constraint is not in posynomial form since it contains reciprocals of posynomials.

I was hoping to apply the trick explained in [Sec. 5.1](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/gp_tutorial.pdf) to transform these inequalities as

$$
\left(\sum_{j\in S_1^c} y_j\right) \le t_j\
\\
\left(\sum_{l\in S_2^c} y_l\right) \le t_l\
\\
\left(t_j\prod_{i\in S_1} x_i \right)^{-1} + \left(t_l\prod_{k\in S_2} x_k \right)^{-1} \le 1,
$$
where $t_i, t_j$ are positive auxiliary variables. The method in [Sec. 5.1](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/gp_tutorial.pdf) is however presented for fractional positive powers of posynomials.

In the reference, they explain that if the $t$ are increasing functions of the $f(y)$ in the constraints (in this case $\sum_{j}y_j$ for example) then the constraints should be equivalent. Can someone provide an explanation of why this holds or prove that this approach doesn't work for reciprocals of posynomials?

Comment: Because now letting $t$ go to infinity always satisfies the constraints, there is nothing to bound you from above. You would need the two linear inequalities to be the other way round but then you don't have a GP though.

Comment: @Michal thanks! Actually I forgot to mention that my objective is a minimization of a posynomial that contains the terms bounded by the t variables, and is "linear" in these terms: something of the type 
$
\min_{x,y} a_{i,j}\left(\prod_{i} x_i \left(\sum_{j} y_j\right)\right) + a_{k,l}\left(\prod_{k} x_k \left(\sum_{l} y_l\right)\right)
$, for some positive . Do you think the trick could work in this case?

Comment: Maybe changing the objective as $$
\min_{x,y,t} a_{i,j}\left(\prod_{i} x_i t_j\right) + a_{k,l}\left(\prod_{k} x_k t_l\right)
$$ would be enough to get an equivalent problem? Now everyhting looks bounded since we minimize over the $t$ variables, but I am not sure the solution is equivalent to the original one.

Comment: Crossposted to OR.SE: [Optimization problem with reciprocal of posynomial](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/10067/491)

Comment: I don't understand your notation. The indices $\ i,j,k,l\ $ appear in your objective as both dummy indices (in the sums and products) and as *free* indices (as subscripts of $\ a_{i,j},a_{k,l}\ $).  The latter would appear to make your objective a *set* of posynomials, rather than the *single* posynomial required for your problem to have any hope of being reduced to a geometric programming problem.

Comment: Also, I think you need to spell out more clearly what your constraints are.  Do I understand correctly that they're
\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{i\in X_{1,m}}x_i\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{j\in Y_{1,m}}y_j\right)^{-1}+\left(\prod_{k\in X_{2,m}}x_k\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{l\in Y_{2,m}}y_l\right)^{-1}\\\le1
\end{align}
for some sets of indices $\ X_{1,m}, X_{2,m},Y_{1,m},Y_{2,m}\ $ and $\ m=1,2,\dots,n\ $? You say explicitly that $\ Y_{1,m},Y_{2,m}\ $ are different sets.  What about $\ X_{1,m}\ $ and $\ X_{2,m}\ $? Are they also different sets?

Comment: What do you mean by "set of posynomials"?  In the end, expaning the sums in the  objective, you get a sum of posynomials, and hence a posynomial by closedness under addition.  For what concerns the constraints, you are correct, and the set $X_{1,m}$ and $X_{2,m}$ are indeed different.

Comment: @Apprentice.  Your objective is $$a_{i,j}\left(\prod_{i\in S_1} x_i \left(\sum_{j\in S_1^c} y_j\right)\right) + a_{k,l}\left(\prod_{k\in S_2} x_k \left(\sum_{l\in S_2^c} y_l\right)\right)\ .$$ For any *fixed* values of the $i,j,k,l$ appearing as subscripts in $a_{i,j},a_{k,l}$ this is a single posynomial, but (assuming  $a_{i,j},a_{k,l}$ are non-constant functions of their subscripts) different values of $i,j,k,l$ will give you different posynomials. By "set of posynomials" I mean the set that you will get by letting the indices $i,j,k,l$ range over all their possible values.